# IntelliJ - how does one show and hide just the right panel?

Tags: intellij-idea

I can show and hide various windows (eg, cmd + 1)
I can hide all windows cmd + shft + f12

What I would like is a shortcut to hide and show the whole of the right panel.  Sometimes I'm working on something and I just need the extra screenspace momentarily.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html, Hide all tool windows attached to the same tool window bar﻿:

Do one of the following:
Press and hold ⌘, and click hide on the title bar of any of the tool windows attached to the corresponding tool window bar.
Choose Window | Active Tool Window | Hide Side Tool Windows in the main menu. This command hides all the tool windows attached to same tool window bar as the active tool window or the last of the active tool windows.

Comment: 'Active Tool Window' doesn't let me choose between the left and right panes, it is just the last window accessed.  Also there is no way of bringing the tool windows back to the same state.  
Thank you again but unfortunately this isn't a solution for what I'm trying to do.  
I just want hide the left pane and then restore it as it was, or the right, or the bottom...all independently.